# Is there a "top-level' package for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apt, package-management

With a really dumb move, I removed the pulseaudio package on my machine and reinstalled it.
The resulting desktop is broken (all the packages that are dependent on pulseaudio have not been reinstalled) i.e. I have no sound :-)

Is there a package whose dependencies can  restore a working system? I was thinking of maybe the desktop (unity), or in a ideal world a meta package for the whole distro. Or am I looking at a complete reinstall from a live-CD?

Comment: visit: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies and broken packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)..

Comment: Reviewers: this is *not* a duplicate ( at least not of that question ).

Answer (score 4):

Usually it's called `ubuntu-desktop`. If you are using some other flavour like Kubuntu, Lubuntu, etc., the package would be `kubuntu-desktop`, `lubuntu-desktop`, etc.